# Snap.svg hover/unhover bug (for longer unhover)

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

If I make a circle and then animate it like this - everything works:

```
  var s = Snap(200,200);
  var c = s.circle(100,100,100);

  c.hover(function(){
  c.animate({fill:"red"}, 500, mina.easeinout);
  }, function() {
  c.animate({ fill:"black" }, 500, mina.easeinout);   
  });
```

It changes the color to red on hover and on "unhover" it goes back to black. But if I make the time in the second function (unhover) 1500 instead of 500 you'll notice that if you hover over the circle, then unhover and hover AGAIN before in less than 1.5 seconds (before the circle's black again) - it will animate to full red and the rapidly go black without animation. Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Drasik/5bcu4rc5/1/

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation to black is still running, so if you hover again 500ms after hovering out, you're telling it to turn red in 500ms, then black again in 1000ms (and I think the browser gets confused, hence the suddenness).

To avoid this, you can try to stop the fade to black animation when hovering back in, like this (https://jsfiddle.net/5bcu4rc5/3/):

```
c.hover(function(){
    c.stop(); // stops the black fill from continuing
    c.animate({fill:"red"}, 500, mina.easeinout);
}, function() {
    c.animate({ fill:"black" }, 1500, mina.easeinout);
});
```

If alternatively you want to force the full 1500ms to run before the red fill can start, maybe something like this (though there are probably better ways: https://jsfiddle.net/5bcu4rc5/2/):

```
c.hover(function(){
    if (c.className != "unhovering") {
        c.animate({fill:"red"}, 500, mina.easeinout);
    }
}, function() {
    c.className = "unhovering";
    c.animate({ fill:"black" }, 1500, mina.easeinout, function() {
        c.className = "";
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the trick with stopping the animation works great :)